# Firebase Crashlytics Invalid Key Error

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I want to integrate Firebase Crashlytics into my Android game (developed using Cocos2D-X engine).

I have followed the steps mentioned in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).

I'm getting following error when building the project using Android Studio:

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully!
```

It looks like that I am missing some API key. How can I find the **Crashlytics API** key in Firebase? How to mention that key in the Android project?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thought on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your `manifest.xml` file? I guess there must be an invalid meta data for crashlytics.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, I can't share the manifest file but I don't have any meta data (related to crashlytics) included in the manifest.xml file. Do you know how to include that meta data?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. A couple of questions - have you ever used Fabric or Crashlytics outside of Firebase before? If not, make sure you've gone through the full Firebase setup here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup before setting up Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Mike Bonnell. I haven't used Fabric or Crashlytics outside Firebase. But, I am using Firebase analytics using [this](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/firebase/v3-cpp/) plugin. Do I still need to go for full Firebase setup?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back to "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1" in my project build.gradle file fixed the problem for me.

The Firebase docs say to use version 4.1.0, which if you follow will give the error above.

Comment: Same for me. 4.1.0 seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

Please note the following things, this should solve your issue:

1. Check Android Studio version, suggested version is 3.1.4.
2. Classpath (project-level *build.gradle* file shouldn't have any alpha or beta versions. That is because Firebase only supports [stable version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/) of Android Studio.

That said, the recommended setup of your gradle version is:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crashlytics requires the Google services Gradle plugin (com.google.gms:google-services) in your build script to process the google-services.json file at build time. However, Crashlytics does work on devices that do not have Google Play services.

I have added this line at end of `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```