# Invalid Crashlytics API Key error when upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.0

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

After upgrading from Android Gradle Plugin `3.2.0` to `3.3.0-alpha13`, I'm seeing the following build error:

```
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug FAILED
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

It appears that the `processDebugGoogleServices` task is no longer running before the `fabricGenerateResourcesDebug` task.

I'm on version `4.1.0` of the Google Services plugin and `1.25.4` of the Fabric plugin.

Comment: Check my answer on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52481929/8244025).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a known incompatibility with the `v4.1.0` plugin and AGP 3.3 alpha versions. The workaround is to downgrade to `v4.0.2` of the `google-services` plugin. More discussion and details may be found here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/pull/661.

Comment: 4.2.0 + AGP 3.3.0 is not working in my specific build for some reason. Reverting to 4.0.2 works, though. :/

Answer (score 19):

`google-services 4.2.0` also fixes the problem.

`platforms/android/build.gradle`

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

to

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case update of `google-services` solve the issue

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```